# Always getting Suspected Fraud status in Paypal transaction - Magento 1.8.0

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, paypal

I have set up Paypal Payments Standard in Magento 1.8.0 but i am always getting *Suspected Fraud* status for each transaction/payment i make.
This is quite frustrating since i don't get this error while in Sandbox Mode and i have to do real transactions to test this behavior.

In Magento **Paypal configuration** i have

```
Payment Action: Sale
Transfer Cart Line Items: No
Enable SSL verification: No
```

I have also installed this extension https://github.com/magento-hackathon/PaypalRoundBugfix and disabled *Transfer Cart Line Items* to avoid differences between the prices sent from Magento and calculated by Paypal. Infact the amounts are exactly the same. I have also tried with the above configurations set to *yes* and without that extension installed, but with no luck.

In Magento if i go to the **Order detail** under the Payment Information tab i have

```
Payer Status: verified
Payer Address Status: unconfirmed
```

While in the **Comments History** there is written

```
Suspected Fraud
Customer Notification Not Applicable 
IPN "Completed". Order is suspended as its capture amount € 2,22 is suspected to be fraudulent. Transaction ID: "9FN02..........".
```

While in the **Transaction detail**, the transaction data is

```
Transaction ID: 9FN02..........
Parent Transaction ID: N/A
Order ID: 200000021
Transaction Type: capture
Is Closed: No
```

What could be the problem?

At the moment i am on a test environment so the website has SSL but it is still not verified since there is no domain pointing to the server yet (this is the reason why i disabled SSL verification for the moment). DNS change will be done before going live.
In Paypal everything is set as its default values/settings, no fees or shipping costs are defined.
I am using Magento for tax calculation, no extensions.

Please i really hope someone can help me out, i have been trying for the last days but found no solution.
Thanks

Comment: Nobody?? I have contacted the Paypal support too but they were not able to provide a solution. Do you have any hint on why the Payer Address Status: is unconfirmed?
I have also tried to pay without using a Paypal account (using just credit card infos on the Paypal website) but the problem is the same.

Comment: I confirm I have the same problem
v.1.7.0.2
problems began in September

Comment: We just  got this notification for the first time, yesterday. There were two payments captured in PayPal for the same amount on one order and Magento got two IPNs.